# Build of kivy-ios app in Xcode 11.5 failing with Python syntax errors

Tags: python, ios, xcode, kivy

I have built my kivy app for iOS using the toolchain. Post opening the generated xcode project and starting the build process I receive the following error.

```
Listing '/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/stopwining-ios/stopwining.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/martinprater.xcuserdatad/xcschemes'...
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/.buildozer/android/app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/ipaddress.py:1106: SyntaxWarning: 'str' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
  raise TypeError("%s and %s are not of the same version" (a, b))
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/stopwiningmobile/kivy/extras/highlight.py:45: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
  if len(sys.argv) is not 4:
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/stopwiningmobile/kivy/uix/behaviors/focus.py:463: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  walk_tree = 'walk' if focus_dir is 'focus_next' else 'walk_reverse'
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/stopwiningmobile/kivy/uix/behaviors/focus.py:476: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if focus_dir is 'focus_next':
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/stopwiningmobile/kivy/uix/behaviors/knspace.py:460: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
  if parent_knspace is not 0:
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/build/hostpython3/x86_64/Python-3.8.2/Lib/lib2to3/tests/data/py3_test_grammar.py:652: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if 1 is 1: pass
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/build/hostpython3/x86_64/Python-3.8.2/Lib/lib2to3/tests/data/py3_test_grammar.py:653: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
  if 1 is not 1: pass
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/build/hostpython3/x86_64/Python-3.8.2/Lib/lib2to3/tests/data/py3_test_grammar.py:656: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if 1 < 1 > 1 == 1 >= 1 <= 1 != 1 in 1 not in 1 is 1 is not 1: pass
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/build/python3/arm64/Python-3.8.2/Lib/lib2to3/tests/data/py3_test_grammar.py:652: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if 1 is 1: pass
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/build/python3/arm64/Python-3.8.2/Lib/lib2to3/tests/data/py3_test_grammar.py:653: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
  if 1 is not 1: pass
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/build/python3/arm64/Python-3.8.2/Lib/lib2to3/tests/data/py3_test_grammar.py:656: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if 1 < 1 > 1 == 1 >= 1 <= 1 != 1 in 1 not in 1 is 1 is not 1: pass
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/build/python3/x86_64/Python-3.8.2/Lib/lib2to3/tests/data/py3_test_grammar.py:652: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if 1 is 1: pass
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/build/python3/x86_64/Python-3.8.2/Lib/lib2to3/tests/data/py3_test_grammar.py:653: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
  if 1 is not 1: pass
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/build/python3/x86_64/Python-3.8.2/Lib/lib2to3/tests/data/py3_test_grammar.py:656: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if 1 < 1 > 1 == 1 >= 1 <= 1 != 1 in 1 not in 1 is 1 is not 1: pass
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/dist/hostpython3/lib/python3.8/lib2to3/tests/data/py3_test_grammar.py:652: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if 1 is 1: pass
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/dist/hostpython3/lib/python3.8/lib2to3/tests/data/py3_test_grammar.py:653: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
  if 1 is not 1: pass
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/dist/hostpython3/lib/python3.8/lib2to3/tests/data/py3_test_grammar.py:656: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if 1 < 1 > 1 == 1 >= 1 <= 1 != 1 in 1 not in 1 is 1 is not 1: pass
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/dist/hostpython3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/ipaddress.py:1106: SyntaxWarning: 'str' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
  raise TypeError("%s and %s are not of the same version" (a, b))
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/ipaddress.py:1106: SyntaxWarning: 'str' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
  raise TypeError("%s and %s are not of the same version" (a, b))
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/stopwining-ios/YourApp/.buildozer/android/app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/ipaddress.py:1106: SyntaxWarning: 'str' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
  raise TypeError("%s and %s are not of the same version" (a, b))
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/stopwining-ios/YourApp/build/hostpython3/x86_64/Python-3.8.2/Lib/lib2to3/tests/data/py3_test_grammar.py:652: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if 1 is 1: pass
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/stopwining-ios/YourApp/build/hostpython3/x86_64/Python-3.8.2/Lib/lib2to3/tests/data/py3_test_grammar.py:653: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
  if 1 is not 1: pass
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/stopwining-ios/YourApp/build/hostpython3/x86_64/Python-3.8.2/Lib/lib2to3/tests/data/py3_test_grammar.py:656: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if 1 < 1 > 1 == 1 >= 1 <= 1 != 1 in 1 not in 1 is 1 is not 1: pass
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/stopwining-ios/YourApp/build/python3/arm64/Python-3.8.2/Lib/lib2to3/tests/data/py3_test_grammar.py:652: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if 1 is 1: pass
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/stopwining-ios/YourApp/build/python3/arm64/Python-3.8.2/Lib/lib2to3/tests/data/py3_test_grammar.py:653: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
  if 1 is not 1: pass
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/stopwining-ios/YourApp/build/python3/arm64/Python-3.8.2/Lib/lib2to3/tests/data/py3_test_grammar.py:656: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if 1 < 1 > 1 == 1 >= 1 <= 1 != 1 in 1 not in 1 is 1 is not 1: pass
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/stopwining-ios/YourApp/build/python3/x86_64/Python-3.8.2/Lib/lib2to3/tests/data/py3_test_grammar.py:652: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if 1 is 1: pass
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/stopwining-ios/YourApp/build/python3/x86_64/Python-3.8.2/Lib/lib2to3/tests/data/py3_test_grammar.py:653: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
  if 1 is not 1: pass
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/stopwining-ios/YourApp/build/python3/x86_64/Python-3.8.2/Lib/lib2to3/tests/data/py3_test_grammar.py:656: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if 1 < 1 > 1 == 1 >= 1 <= 1 != 1 in 1 not in 1 is 1 is not 1: pass
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/stopwining-ios/YourApp/dist/hostpython3/lib/python3.8/lib2to3/tests/data/py3_test_grammar.py:652: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if 1 is 1: pass
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/stopwining-ios/YourApp/dist/hostpython3/lib/python3.8/lib2to3/tests/data/py3_test_grammar.py:653: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
  if 1 is not 1: pass
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/stopwining-ios/YourApp/dist/hostpython3/lib/python3.8/lib2to3/tests/data/py3_test_grammar.py:656: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if 1 < 1 > 1 == 1 >= 1 <= 1 != 1 in 1 not in 1 is 1 is not 1: pass
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/stopwining-ios/YourApp/dist/hostpython3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/ipaddress.py:1106: SyntaxWarning: 'str' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
  raise TypeError("%s and %s are not of the same version" (a, b))
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/stopwining-ios/YourApp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/ipaddress.py:1106: SyntaxWarning: 'str' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
  raise TypeError("%s and %s are not of the same version" (a, b))
/Users/martinprater/ios/stopwining-ios/YourApp/stopwining-ios/YourApp/stopwining-ios/YourApp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/ipaddress.py:1106: SyntaxWarning: 'str' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
  raise TypeError("%s and %s are not of the same version" (a, b))
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

It appears to be a mismatch in python versions.
Running the compile script directly from my virtual environment works without any errors:

```
/Users/martinprater/ios/dist/hostpython3/bin/python -m compileall -f -b "$PROJECT_DIR"/YourApp
```

I have tried setting the Python environment both globally through pyenv and through a pre-build script to enforce using Python 3.8.2.
However, it does not seem to take effect in Xcode (11.5).

I have tried:

- Using virtual env and global installation with the same effect.
- Python 3.7 and Python 3.8 -> same effect
- Reinstalling Xcode and rebuilding all recipes -> no change.

Any help warmly appreciated.
Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

For fixing this issue we have to change **==** to **is**
here is the full blog https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/01/21/why-does-python-3-8-syntaxwarning-for-is-literal/

Comment: First of all: No! We have to change "is" to "==" and "is not" to "!=". Secondly: Many of the files are in a sub-folder called "lib2to3/tests/data/". Are they actually necessary? Can't they just be excluded from the build process?